# Python AttributeError;;

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Code
    import requests 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
LIMIT = 50
URL = f"https://au.indeed.com/jobs?q=Python&limit={LIMIT}&radius=50"

def extract_indeed_pages():
  result = requests.get(URL)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
  pagination = soup.find("div", {"class":"pagination"})
  links = pagination.find_all("a")
  pages = []
  for link in links[:-1]:
      pages.append(int(link.string))
  max_page = pages[-1]
  return max_page



def extract_indeed_jobs(last_page):
  jobs = []
  # for page in range(last_page):
  result = requests.get(f"{URL}&start={0*LIMIT}")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
  results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "jobsearch-SerpJobCard"})
  for result in results:
      title = result.find("div", {"class": "title"}).find("a")["title"]
      company = result.find("span", {"class": "company"})
      if company is None:
        print(company.find("a").string)
      else:
        print(company.string)
  return jobs
```

Result

```
DisplayrNoneAkuna CapitalNone

Akuna CapitalNoneAkuna Capital
TechSkills Accelerator
NoneNoneWestbury PartnersNone

Inflexi Technologies Pvt. Ltd.Akuna CapitalNone
Optiver
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>    indeed_jobs = extract_indeed_jobs(last_indeed_page)  File "/home/runner/python-course/indeed.py", line 30
, in extract_indeed_jobs
    print(company.find("a").string)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find’
```

I don't want to see none and just want to see company name.
I tried to solve this problem but, I  couldn't solve this.
I appreciate of your advice

Comment: I think company is None ,just print company to see if the company is none or giving any string

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to print the None string, you can simply put like this

```
  if company is not None:
    print(company.find("a").string)
```

Or for any reason you want it than make it

```
  if company is not None:
    print(company.find("a").string)
  if company is None:
    print(company)
```

Comment: umm...I already tried this way but It also was an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' has no attribute 'string'

Comment: if your problem is resolved kindly upvote and accept the answer